# Idiomatic iterator + mutation on a struct in Rust?

Tags: rust

I just ended up writing this code:

```
/// Watcher to look for changes in files
pub struct Watch<'a> {
  glob:Option<Glob>,
  ruv:Vec<*mut c_void>,
  paths:Vec<Path>,
  pub callback:Option<|Path, WatchEvent|: 'a>
}

impl<'a> Watch<'a> {

  /// Start watching for changes in any of the files matching known patterns
  pub fn watch(&mut self, path:&str) {
    let g = self.glob.take().unwrap();
    for path in g.iter(path) {
      match self.add_unique(&path) {
        Some(p) => { self.bind(&path); },
        None => {}
      }
    }
    self.glob = Some(g);
  }

  /// Check for a matching path
  fn add_unique(&mut self, path:&Path) -> Option<Path> {
    let mut found = false;
    for i in self.paths.iter() {
      if i.as_str().unwrap().as_bytes() == path.dirname() {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if !found {
      self.paths.push(Path::new(path.dirname()));
      return Some(Path::new(path.dirname()));
    }
    return None;
  }

...

}
```

I'm particularly unhappy about having to move glob out of the Watch instance so that I can iterate over path matches and update the state of the object.

I tried a few approaches to this, but all the other alternatives involved creating temporary vectors which is completely infeasible (the glob might match hundreds of files, but I only care about unique paths in the tree of files so that they can be bound to libuv's file events api; I definitely *do not* want to create a vector that contains a gigantic list of every matching file).

How could this be written in a more idiomatic form?

I feel like it could be simplified considerably using functional calls, but the exact semantics for it elude me.

In essence what I'm trying to achieve here is:

```
for every filename in g.iter(path)
  if the path of the filename is not known yet
    call bind() on the path
    save the filename so future calls to watch() dont duplicate watch it
```

Here's a playpen with dummy data showing it in action: http://is.gd/09wYTS

Edit: And here's why I have to move Glob out to iter() on it: http://is.gd/FGlmw5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it, this is typical problem of iterator invalidation. You are trying to modify structure that you are iterating over. When written in C++ it would compile but "magical" things can happen.

Idiomatic way to handle such situations is to create temporary structure for item that you want to insert and then insert them outside of the for loop.

Something along the lines:

```
pub fn watch(&mut self, path:&str) {
  let temp = Vec::new();
  for path in self.glob.iter(path) {
    match self.would_add_unique(&path) {
      Some(p) => { self.bind(&p); temp.push_back(&p); },
      None => {}
    }
  }

  for item in temp.iter() {
    self.add_unique(&item);
  }
}
```

Or you can redesign your structures so they do not act as single value.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not really happy creating an arbitrary temporary vector (which might be large) either, but I guess it's better than moving a value out.