# How do I modify a collection without consuming it?

Tags: performance, rust, allocation

I want to modify a collection in place before returning it:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", compute()); // should print [[2, 1, 0], [5, 4, 3]]
}

// u8 is just a placeholder, so impl Copy is considered cheating :)
fn compute() -> Vec<Vec<u8>> {
    let a = vec![0, 1, 2];
    let b = vec![3, 4, 5];

    let mut result = Vec::new();
    result.push(a);
    result.push(b);

    // avoids allocations from:
    //
    // result.iter()
    //     .map(|r| {
    //         r.reverse()
    //         r
    //     })
    //     .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    result.into_iter().for_each(|mut r| r.reverse());

    // errors out: the collection was consumed the line above
    result
}
```

A collection was already allocated with `Vec::new()`, so allocating a second collection here seems like a waste. I am assuming that's what `.collect()` does.

1. How do I avoid the allocation in excess?
2. Is there any easy way to know how many allocations are happening? In golang it was as easy as `go test -bench=.`, but I can't find anything similar when it comes to Rust.

---

[Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1adfbabcb5ed7f5066e9116d8563168e)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an elegant solution to modifying a structure while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322932/is-there-an-elegant-solution-to-modifying-a-structure-while-iterating)

Comment: `iter_mut` would be the way to go (or `into_iter` on a `&mut` reference to the same vector). [Applied to your question](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=82fa780ce61db23039f701929533dcff)

Comment: It answers 1.) If you make it into a question I'll accept your answer today and open a new Q with 2.) alone, unless somebody also answers number 2.) Thanks!

Comment: Questions should stick to one fundamental question per post, so it should indeed be made into a separate question.

Comment: 2 short answer: `valgrind --tool massif`. 2 long answer: [Build](https://fasterthanli.me/articles/small-strings-in-rust) your own tracing allocator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `&mut` to each of the inside vectors, for that you can just use `iter_mut` which uses `&mut Self` instead of `Self` for the outer vector.

```rust
// u8 is just a placeholder, so impl Copy is considered cheating :)
fn compute() -> Vec<Vec<u8>> {
    let a = vec![0, 1, 2];
    let b = vec![3, 4, 5];

    let mut result = Vec::new();
    result.push(a);
    result.push(b);

    result.iter_mut().for_each(|r| r.reverse());

    result
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=45f4588d6b9dde7cc42491aec69550d2)